# Please help with wordpress hide input if empty with custom field

Tags: wordpress, field

I made a slider what i can hide if is check a check box.

I even gave it an input where you can add the folder locaton, but i cant make it to hide if the folder is empty or its not correct

this is the code

```
<?php if(is_category(7) || is_page(11) && get_post_meta($post->ID, 'm_slider', true) == 'true' || 11 == $post->post_parent && get_post_meta($post->ID, 'm_slider', true) == 'true') {?>
<div id='slider_bg'>
</div><!-- slider_bg -->
<div id='slider_img'>
<div class="slider" >
<img src='<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/slider/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'main_folder', true); ?>/1.jpg'>
<img src='<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/slider/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'main_folder', true); ?>/2.jpg'>
<img src='<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/slider/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'main_folder', true); ?>/3.jpg'>
<img src='<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/slider/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'main_folder', true); ?>/4.jpg'>

</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

i tryed to give it to a variable and if its empty than hide it not working i tryed wit if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'main_folder', true) !== '')

and that doesnt work either, could please someone give me a hint what im missin?

Answer (score 0):

You could try :

```
$themeRoot = get_theme_root();
$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'main_folder', true);
if ( !empty($meta) && is_dir($themeRoot . '/slider/' . $meta) )
{
    # test here if the folder is empty or not and act acordingly 
    #  http://iarematt.com/php-code-to-check-if-a-directory-is-empty/
}
```

Comment: thank you for your anwser but it still not working no mather how i combine, guess i give up, but really thanks